# Alternative Check for martingale property

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Why is it enough to check the usual martingale property in the following way?

$X_t$ is a martingale iff $s<t$, $Y$ is $\mathbb{F}_s$ measurable and $\mathbb{E}[YX_s]=\mathbb{E}[YX_t]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose you have the proper integrability assumptions of $Y$ and $X_t$.

For the if part, given $A\in\mathbb{F}_s$, then $1_A$ is $\mathbb{F}_s$ measurable, hence by assumption, $$E[1_AX_s]=E[1_A X_t],\tag{1}$$ which is equivalent to the requirement of martingale that 
$$\int_{A}X_t=\int_A E[X_t\mid\mathbb{F}_s]=\int_A X_s,\quad \forall A\in \mathbb{F}_s.$$

For the only if part, suppose $X_t$ is a martingale, then (1) holds. Then similar identities hold for simple functions and integrable functions by passing to limit.